# Как можно вывести на экран название переменной?

Tags: python

Хочу вывести на кран название переменной.

Есть какой-нибудь метод, чтобы при использовании в коде вместо знаков вопроса можно было написать и вывести на экран название переменной (Что-то на подобии метода __name __()  у функций)?

```
def sample_func():
  pass
sample_value = {}
sample_value['my_key'] = 45

print(sample_value.__repr__())  # {'my_key': 45}
print(sample_func.__name__)     # sample_func
# ?????                         # sample_value
```

Comment: Тут толпа вариантов в ответах. Но простого встроенного варианта нет. У самих переменных просто нет такого поля как "имя". Нужно перебирать все локальные переменные и смотреть, какая из них искомая. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string

Answer (score 0):

В Python нельзя получить название переменной напрямую, но можно попробовать найти название переменной через подбор значений переменных.

```
def get_variable_name(var):
    variables = globals()
    for name, value in variables.items():
        if value is var:
            return name
    return None

x = 42
variable_name = get_variable_name(x)
print(variable_name)
```

Единственным минусом этого кода является возможное отсутствие правильного ответа при одинаковых значений у нескольких переменных.

Comment: Ну кстати да, если сделать вторую переменную со значением 42, то они обе будут иметь одинаковый id.

Comment: Да, я понял. Хотел просто самописный логер реализовать, но понял что лучший вариант остается тупо принт =)